# C++ Builder support for __time64_t?

Tags: c++builder

It appears that C++ Builder lacks support for `__time64_t` and `time64()`. Is that correct, or is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Which version of C++Builder are you using, and which platform(s) are you targetting? And why do you want to use `time64()` at all? There are plenty of other ways to work with date/time values in C++Builder. What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. According to [Visual Studio documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64?view=msvc-170), `_time64()` would be found in *time.h*, but it is not there (or in any other file). So it is strictly Visual Studio specific function.

`__time32_t` and `__time64_t` are defined (*io.h* and *sys\types.h*), but they are kind of useless without the corresponding functions.

Note that on 64-bit target, `time()` returns 64-bit result: From *include\windows\crtl\time.h*

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
typedef __int64 time_t;
#else
typedef long time_t;
#endif
```